# Can't modify struct property since "Function call returns immutable value"

Tags: swift

I have a struct, called "enemy" with two properties:

```
struct enemy {
var hp = 0
var dam = 0
}
```

I have a function that rolls a dice (I know not the neatest way to do it but I'm emulating the real-life process), and I call that function in another function to decide enemy values during an enemy encounter.

My diceRoll function (I know this works since I use it elsewhere)

```
func diceRoll(roll: Int) {
outcome = roll
}
```

And finally the bit in question that's not working:

```
func decideEnemyStats() {
diceRoll(roll: Int(arc4random_uniform(6) + 1));
enemy().hp = outcome
}
```

I get this error:

cannot assign to property: function call returns immutable value

why?

Comment: The error message says "why". Read it again and trust what it says. As it is written the code makes no sense (and thankfully this can be caught as part of the typesystem).

Comment: `enemy()` creates a new (temporary) `enemy` object. This is why you should follow the convention of capitalizing type names: `Enemy` :)

Comment: @jtbandes how would capitalizing my type name help?

Comment: It makes it harder to confuse with variable names which are conventionally lowercased.

Comment: @jtbandes so there's no way to pass a value to enemy().hp?

Comment: What would you want that to do?

Comment: @jtbandes I want to be able to have a temporary enemy instance for each enemy encounter, with the stats for the enemy determined at random through diceroll.

Comment: And then what should happen to that enemy object?